# Unable to convert JSON to XML correctly in javascript

Tags: javascript, xml-parsing, casperjs

When I load [this](https://de.dpdhl.jobs/search-jobs/results?ActiveFacetID=0&CurrentPage=1&RecordsPerPage=20&Distance=50&ShowRadius=False&SearchResultsModuleName=Search%20Results&SearchFiltersModuleName=Search%20Filters&SortCriteria=0&SortDirection=1&SearchType=5) link, I get a `JSON` object. This object contain the `XML` data. I need to get the data from inside those tags, traversing through the class name and I am more interested in the data with class name `job-entry`.

What I did is, I converted this `JSON` data into xml first through [json2xml](http://goessner.net/download/prj/jsonxml/xmljson_test.html)
 function. Which successfully gave me the `XML`. And then I wished to traverse through the DOM of this `XML`, so I did this :

```js
var xml_string = json2xml(json_string);
var parser = new DOMParser();
var xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(xml_string, "text/xml");
```

Where, `json_string` is the one which I load from the link. And then I parse it. According to [this tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_parser.asp), I am traversing through the DOM now, and I am getting the error :

> undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'xml_string.getElementsByClassName("job-entry")');

This is how I travers through the DOM, and I don't now where I am missing it.
Note that I am using casper JS to load the JSON.

```js
var jobsURL = "https://de.dpdhl.jobs/search-jobs/results?ActiveFacetID=0&CurrentPage=1&RecordsPerPage=20&Distance=50&ShowRadius=False&SearchResultsModuleName=Search+Results&SearchFiltersModuleName=Search+Filters&SortCriteria=0&SortDirection=1&SearchType=5";

casper.start(jobsURL);
casper.then(function() {

  var json_string = JSON.parse(this.getPageContent());
  var xml_string = json2xml(json_string);
  var parser = new DOMParser();
  var xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(xml_string, "text/xml");


  console.log(xml_string.getElementsByClassName("job-entry")[0].textContent);

})


casper.run();
```

Comment: Your code snippets don't have required dependencies and are broken. Would be better with a working jsfiddle instead.

Comment: @Frederik.L I am using casper JS , and don`t know how would it work with JSFiddle

Comment: Something seems to go wrong while inside `json2xml(json_string)`. Maybe it is expected that you use a json string instead of an object? The `JSON.parse(...)` method will return an object litteral.

Comment: Still no work @Frederik.L

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems that are preventing you from achieving your goal.

**Number 1:** The resulting XML that comes from `json2xml` appears to contain errors.

[XML Validator](https://codebeautify.org/xmlvalidator) throws the following error:

```
XML Parsing Error: not well-formed
Location: https://codebeautify.org/xmlvalidator
Line Number 20, Column 217:
                                <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off" id="category-filter-2" class="filter-checkbox" data-facet-type="1" data-id="23821" data-count="15" data-display="Division Customer Solutions & Innovation" data-field-name="" />
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------^
```

**Number 2:** You are attempting to run `getElementsByClassName()` on `xml_string`, rather than `xmlDoc`.

**Number 3:** `getElementsByClassName()` does not work on XML elements. This is an HTML function.

You are better off using XPath (XML Path Language) when it comes to selecting elements in XML.

Since your XML is invalid, I can provide a solution to your problem using sample XML.

---

### Full Solution:

**CasperJS Program:**

```
var jobsURL = 'https://de.dpdhl.jobs/search-jobs/results?ActiveFacetID=0&CurrentPage=1&RecordsPerPage=20&Distance=50&ShowRadius=False&SearchResultsModuleName=Search+Results&SearchFiltersModuleName=Search+Filters&SortCriteria=0&SortDirection=1&SearchType=5';

var casper = require('casper').create();

casper.start(jobsURL);

casper.then(function () {
  // Sample XML
  var xml_string = '<omega><root><tower>716379923</tower><job class="job-entry">Veterinary Physician</job><modern>red</modern><written>individual</written><low>help</low><other>689533135.2394588</other></root><root><tower>234423546</tower><job class="job-entry">Software Developer</job><modern>green</modern><written>multiple</written><low>pain</low><other>99999.11111111111</other></root><root><tower>002229385</tower><job class="job-entry">Car Salesman</job><modern>brown</modern><written>absence</written><low>love</low><other>23408.55728904901</other></root></omega>';
  var parser = new DOMParser();
  var xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(xml_string, 'text/xml');
  var job_entry = xmlDoc.evaluate('//*[@class="job-entry"]', xmlDoc, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
  var current_job_entry = job_entry.iterateNext();
  
  while (current_job_entry) {
    this.echo(current_job_entry.textContent);
    current_job_entry = job_entry.iterateNext();
  }
});

casper.run();
```

**Result:**

```
Veterinary Physician
Software Developer
Car Salesman
```

**Sample XML:**

```
<omega>
  <root>
    <tower>716379923</tower>
    <job class="job-entry">Veterinary Physician</job>
    <modern>red</modern>
    <written>individual</written>
    <low>help</low>
    <other>689533135.2394588</other>
  </root>
  <root>
    <tower>234423546</tower>
    <job class="job-entry">Software Developer</job>
    <modern>green</modern>
    <written>multiple</written>
    <low>pain</low>
    <other>99999.11111111111</other>
  </root>
  <root>
    <tower>002229385</tower>
    <job class="job-entry">Car Salesman</job>
    <modern>brown</modern>
    <written>absence</written>
    <low>love</low>
    <other>23408.55728904901</other>
  </root>
</omega>
```